# Script to compare 2 files line by line

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, file-comparison

I have two text files:

File1.txt

```
dadads 434 43 {"4fsdf":"66db1" fdf1:"5834"}
gsgss 45 0 {"gsdg":"8853" sgdfg:"4631"}
fdf 767 4643 {"klhf":"3455" kgs:"4566"}
.  
.
```

File2.txt

```
8853
6437437567
36265
4566
.
.
```

Output could be two files

Match.txt

```
gsgss 45 0 {"gsdg":"8853" sgdfg:"4631"}
fdf 767 4643 {"klhf":"3455" kgs:"4566"}
```

Non_Match.txt

```
dadads 434 43 {"4fsdf":"66db1" fdf1:"5834"}
```

Can someone help me write bash script for this?

I think i have the logic here if it helps:

```
 for (rows in File1.txt) {
   bool found = false;
    for (id in File2.txt) {
      if (row contains id) {
      found = true;
      echo row >> Match.txt
      break;
     }
    }
   if (!found) {
      echo row >> Non_Match.txt
   }
  }
```

Edit Part:

I also have a bash script but its not helping as it is not putting the row which matches but instead only the ID that matches..

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

file1="File2.txt"
file2="File1.txt"

for id in $(tail -n+1 "${file1}"); do
   if ! grep "${id}" "${file2}"; then
      echo "${id}" >>non_matches.txt
   else
       echo "${id}" >>matches.txt
   fi
done
```

Comment: `diff` compares files *line-by-line* but with line equivalence.

Comment: I don't think a regular diff command can do what i am looking for.

Comment: Your logic looks sound, you should *try writing the script* rather than asking random internet strangers to do it for you.

Comment: @user175084: you could use `wdiff`...

Comment: Also the files are 1.8M and 15M.. will wdiff support it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `grep -f` to look for search patterns that are listed in a separate file. It'd probably be good to use the `-F` (fixed strings) and `-w` (match whole words) flags as well.

```
grep -Fw  -f File2.txt File1.txt > Match.txt
grep -Fwv -f File2.txt File1.txt > Non_Match.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like `diff` or `wdiff` if you want to do this on word level.

If you run `diff` on your two files, you will generate the following output:

```
< dadads 434 43 {"4fsdf":"66db1" fdf1:"5834"}
< gsgss 45 0 {"gsdg":"8853" sgdfg:"4631"}
< fdf 767 4643 {"klhf":"3455" kgs:"4566"}
---
> 8853
> 6437437567
> 36265
> 4566
```

It means that the "minimal" way (per *line*) to modify the first file into the second is removing all lines and add all new lines.

If however the second file would have been:

```
8853
6437437567
gsgss 45 0 {"gsdg":"8853" sgdfg:"4631"}
36265
4566
```

The `diff` output is:

```
1c1,2
< dadads 434 43 {"4fsdf":"66db1" fdf1:"5834"}
---
> 8853
> 6437437567
3c4,5
< fdf 767 4643 {"klhf":"3455" kgs:"4566"}
---
> 36265
> 4566
```

So `diff` no longer asks to remove the second line.

`wdiff` does approximately the same, but on word level:

```
[-dadads 434 43 {"4fsdf":"66db1" fdf1:"5834"}-]{+8853
6437437567+}
gsgss 45 0 {"gsdg":"8853" sgdfg:"4631"}
[-fdf 767 4643 {"klhf":"3455" kgs:"4566"}-]
{+36265
4566+}
```